# Asking for Diagnostic database Chronic Lymphocytic Leukemia (CLL)

Tags: data-request, machine-learning

I am an M.A. student of Shahid Beheshti university medical informatics. My thesis is about (Cancer DataMining, Chronic Lymphocytic Leukemia (CLL) diagnostic based on clinical registry. not genomes)... but I could not find these dataset.I could  not also extract diagnostic information from site SEER.
I need to clinical information and CBC: 100 Patient.

please help me
I am looking forward to your reply.

Sincerely Yours

M.SH

Comment: i'm assuming you mean seer data on cancer.gov, what site(s) where you looking at for the other data? sidenote: whoever id voting to close this as "unclear what you're asking", how about asking the user to clarify before shutting them down? new user, 6 points....not a nice way to welcome them.